# How can code go past response.redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got the following code block.  I'm confused how the code can go past the

```
Response.Redirect("~..")
```

Indeed it does.  I thought any lines past that would automatically not execute.  Am I missing somethig basic here?   I find the debugger actually executing the next lines.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx", true);

        string year =
           Utils.ConvertCodeCampYearToActualYear(
               Utils.GetCurrentCodeCampYear().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        var viewModel = GetViewModel(year);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: I think you have a misconception of how the MVC framework functions. This is a webforms approach. ActionResults must return Actions to function.

Comment: even in webforms, Response.Redirect does not stop execution, all code beyond would still be executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `Response.Redirect()` does (really) is set `location=` response header to the specified URI and sets the http status to `302 Found`. It also writes a little stub HTML in the response with a link to the new URI as well, but that's a mere decoration.

Unless you use the overload that allows you to specify whether or not processing should be continued via a `bool` flag, processing continues. If that `bool` flag is true, response processing is terminated by aborting the thread processing the request, throwing a `ThreadAbortException` as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  awesome answers.  I should have looked at it with reflector and I would have know that.  I relapsed into "webforms" thinking and forgot to think about what is really happening.

Answer (score 8):

You need to `return` it. It's a function. In your case you can use `Redirect`:

```
return Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

Comment: and then make the actiontype of the return void?

Comment: Nah leave it as returning an ActionResult